# Reuse the layout for both landscape and portrait

Tags: android, xml

How can I make a layout reuse for both landscape and portrait?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/user_fragment" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you design your layout in a flexible way, then ideally it should look good/acceptable in either portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: Yes I created following constraint model but when I rotate emulators, the layouts don't switch.

Comment: I can confirm that on actual devices the layouts rotate, but not on emulators on my desktop